# psql extract weekly counts and percentage of total

Tags: psql

I am trying to extract from one of our db tables the frequency of a particular type of study which matches the type 'G' (G GAR GER G-R) and also the total number of studies in that week (matches all type) and relative frequency of the 'G's. I want the output grouped into weeks (beginning on monday and ending on friday).

I use `generate_series` to get a range of Mondays over the period of interest

`SELECT (current_date- cast(extract(dow from current_date) as int) + 1) - s.a AS dates FROM generate_series(0,182,7) AS s(a);`

Using the following command

```
FROM (SELECT (current_date- cast(extract(dow from current_date) as int) + 1) - s.a AS dates FROM generate_series(0,182,7) AS s(a)) d
    LEFT JOIN study ON
study_date <= d.dates 
WHERE study_name ~ 'T(C|L)S' and study_type ~'G'                                            
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

I get the following output

```
  dates    | count 
------------+-------
 26/06/2017 |     6
 03/07/2017 |    11
 10/07/2017 |    15
 17/07/2017 |    30
 24/07/2017 |    38
 31/07/2017 |    47
 07/08/2017 |    61
 14/08/2017 |    77
```

This gives me a correct rolling count as we do more studies of type 'G'. However, I  try the following to split this into weekly ranges

```
SELECT d.dates, count(*)                                
FROM (SELECT (current_date- cast(extract(dow from current_date) as int) + 1) - s.a AS dates FROM generate_series(0,182,7) AS s(a)) d
    LEFT JOIN study ON
study_date >= d.dates  
WHERE study_name ~ 'T(C|L)S' and study_type ~ 'G' AND study_date <= myo_date + interval '5' day
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives me output that I do not understand (I was expecting the difference between rows in above output)

```
  dates    | count 
------------+-------
 13/02/2017 |    79
 20/02/2017 |    79
 27/02/2017 |    79
 06/03/2017 |    79
 13/03/2017 |    79
 20/03/2017 |    79
 27/03/2017 |    79
 03/04/2017 |    79
 10/04/2017 |    79
 17/04/2017 |    79
 24/04/2017 |    79
 01/05/2017 |    79
 08/05/2017 |    79
 15/05/2017 |    79
 22/05/2017 |    79
 29/05/2017 |    79
 05/06/2017 |    79
 12/06/2017 |    79
 19/06/2017 |    79
 26/06/2017 |    74
 03/07/2017 |    70
 10/07/2017 |    68
 17/07/2017 |    53
 24/07/2017 |    44
 31/07/2017 |    34
 07/08/2017 |    22
 14/08/2017 |     3
```

How do I get the counts on weekly basis? Also how can I add an additional column total counts where study_type can be anything.

Expected output

```
 dates    | count 
    ------------+-------
     26/06/2017 |    6
     03/07/2017 |    5
     10/07/2017 |    4
     17/07/2017 |    15
     24/07/2017 |    8
     31/07/2017 |    9
     07/08/2017 |    14
     14/08/2017 |    16
```

Comment: What is the second expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen essentially the difference between two rows on the first output. Number of studies performed between the monday and friday where the monday date comes from the series generated

Comment: Done@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I don't believe that any of the code you pasted here would actually run.  Please include a functioning query for your first set of output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `LAG()` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        (current_date- cast(extract(dow from current_date) as int) + 1) - s.a AS dates,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM generate_series(0,182,7) AS s(a)) d
    LEFT JOIN study
        ON study_date <= d.dates 
    WHERE study_name ~ 'T(C|L)S' and study_type ~'G'
    GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT
    dates,
    cnt - LAG(cnt, 0) OVER (ORDER BY dates)
FROM cte;
```

Comment: This gives me `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 1: WITH cte AS (`. ?psql version related (8.4.20)

Comment: @moadeep Your query has a problem.  Edit my answer and place your actual query into the CTE.  I can't read your mind.